# How to save JWT in sveltekit?

Tags: javascript, jwt, session-cookies, svelte, sveltekit

Being new to sveltekit, I have made a login form based on [realworldapp](https://github.com/sveltejs/realworld/blob/master/src/routes/login/index.svelte), which receives JWT token upon successful login.

```
<script context="module">
    export async function load({ session }) {
        if (session.user) {
            return {
                status: 302,
                redirect: '/'
            };
        }
        return {};
    }
</script>

<script>
    import { session } from '$app/stores';
    import { goto } from '$app/navigation';
    import { post } from '$lib/utils.js';
    import { fade } from 'svelte/transition';
 
 
    let username = '';
    let password = '';
    let errors = null;
    let message = '';
    let hasError = false
    async function submit(event) {
        errors = response.errors;
        if (response.token) {
            $session.access_token = response.token.access_token;
            //how to save this token in a cookie?
            goto('/profile');
        } else {
            message= response.message;
            hasError = true
            setTimeout(() => {hasError=false}, 5000);            
        }
    }
</script>

        <form  on:submit|preventDefault={submit} >
            <h3 class="form-title">Login</h3>
            {#if hasError}
                <div  transition:fade  class="err-msg">{message}</div>
            {/if} 
                <input type="text" bind:value={username}  placeholder="username">
                <input type="password" bind:value={password} placeholder="password">
              
                <input type="submit"  value="send">
        </form>
```

It works fine and I can get the token in a response like:

```
{
message: "successully logged in!"
token: {access_token: 'eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1....'
}
```

Now, I'm wondering what is the safe and idomatic way to save the token to a cookie and retrive it, so that usr does not need toauthenticate each time that opens the browser?

I looket at the official docs but could not find any hints about it. Nor could I find a working example in a tutorial about it. Hence the quesiton.

Answer (score 0):

Your core concern is "how do I save a value in a cookie, then retrieve it later?"

[Cookies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/api/document/cookie) are stored in the browser as a string that requires parsing to read or update.  There are many libraries in JavaScript to help you do this, one popular one being [js-cookie](https://www.npmjs.com/package/js-cookie).  While you don't *need* a library, you may find it more convenient than parsing the string yourself.

A basic example of how to write and read a cookie is:

```
import Cookies from 'js-cookie'


Cookies.set('name', 'value');

Cookies.get('name') // => 'value'
```

There are more options you can set too, like the path, the expiry, etc.

Comment: I want to do it safely. I read here is that just saving the jwt in cookie is not safe enough: https://hasura.io/blog/best-practices-of-using-jwt-with-graphql/

Comment: _Anything_ you send to the client is no longer in your control.  It doesn't matter if you intentionally store it or not, once the JWT is sent to the client, it's beyond your control if it ends up someplace else.  The article you linked says as much. A JWT is a "bearer token," which means it's intended to be sent with a request to "prove" the request comes from a valid source.  But there's nothing to stop a client from sharing their token with someone else, for example.  Sorry to be the bearer of bad news, but that's just a fact.

Comment: I think @Kodoxa wants to store the token on the server and have the server make the requests for the client - that way, they never actually interact with the token.

Comment: You should better use a Typescript library. Svelte and SvelteKit are typescript able (and oriented to) so don't trash all that advantage using a JS only library.